# VHT Pitbull 50-CL foot pedal?

Tags: guitar-effects, amplifiers

I'm the proud new owner of a used Pitbull 50-CL I got cheap at guitar center, but it didn't come with a footpedal. Now VHT is Freyette, I'm not sure where I could get one. Could I use something generic if I can't get the real deal?

Answer (score 2):

Pitbulls come with two different types of control connectors for footswitch functions. If your Pitbull uses the standard 1/4" TR connector like this one does:

[image: 1/4 connector]

Then you can use any 1/4" TR type footswitch to control the amp's functions. You'll want latching switches.

Now if it has this DIN-style connector seen here:

[image: DIN-style connector]

Then you're probably better off just [contacting Freyette](http://www.sfdamp.com/support_form.aspx). Sourcing the right plug and wiring up a switch for the functions will probably cost you as much as a new one straight from Freyette. Freyette is a good company and I'm sure they'll be able to help you source one either locally, or get you set up with one from their stock. They still use the DIN-style connector on their newest amps.